# Override onBackPressed to back to a specific Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment(CustomerFrag). My target is that when I press the back button of the device from any other fragment, they all redirect to this one. In order to do this I did override `onBackPressed` method but that doesn't work as I need.

How can I achieve this?

So far I have tried this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    CustomerFrag cf = (CustomerFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Customer");
    if (cf != null){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
        Fragment frag = new CustomerFrag();
        ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
        ft.addToBackStack("back");
        ft.commit();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: please make sure you have the code block after the `if (cf != null)` check between `{}`

Comment: I added `{}` in this post doesn't because i created without IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use additional activity display your other fragments in new activity and when back is pressed - finish it.